# Spoken languages in team radio

Tags: rules, formula-1, auto-racing

I can recall moments from a few years ago when Fernando Alonso would be communicating with his race engineer Andrea Stella in either Italian or English, or sometimes even a mix of both, and they'd play it back that way on team radio.

Nowadays in F1, radio communications in the teams' native languages are noticeably absent.

> Has there been any recent regulations that restrict F1 teams and drivers to communicate only in English whenever they are out on track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On official [limitations on radio communication](https://www.formula1.com/en/latest/features/2016/3/the-2016-season-preview---new-rules--teams--drivers---races.html) there are no indications as to the language to use, so I believe that **there are no restrictions in this regard**

I can add that all pit to car radio transmissions must be open and accessible to both the FIA and broadcasters.